# Play Framework: Count how many times a key exists in a JSON tree and how many times is set to a certain value

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following JSON...

```
{
  "firstName": "Joe",
  "lastName": "Grey",
  ...
  "addresses":
  [
    {
      "name": "Default",
      "street": "...",
      ...,
      "isDefault": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Home",
      "street": "...",
      ...,
      "isDefault": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Office",
      "street": "...",
      ...,
      "isDefault": false
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I count how many times `isDefault` is set to `false` in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way is like this:

```
(json \\ "isDefault").filter(_ == JsBoolean(false)).size
```